# Is is possible to deploy different monorepos packages to different domains

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment, monorepo

I'm trying to deploy a monorepo of 2 react packages (repos) where each package is deployed to different aws s3 bucket , is it possible ?

package A to be deployed to `api.mywebsite.com`

package B to be deployed to `www.mywebsite.com`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

I suggest you do the following

1. In your build step create two artifacts (e.g. `api`, `web`). For example, if your `npm build` creates a `./build` directory,  do `cp -r build api` for the `api` project and similar for the `web` project
2. In your deployment step do something like `aws s3 cp api s3://api.mywebsite.com --recursive` or `aws s3 sync api s3://api.mywebsite.com` and same for the `web` artifact